# How do I mock a PUT request using ring.mock.request

Tags: clojure, mocking, put, ring

How do I make this test pass:

```
(ns imp-rest.parser-test-rest
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all])
  (:require [ring.mock.request :as mock] )
  (:require [imp-rest.web :as w]))

(deftest test-parser-rest
  (testing "put settings"          
           (w/app 
             (mock/request :put "/settings/coordinateName" "FOO" ))

           (let [response (w/app (mock/request :get "/settings"))]
             (println response )
             (is (=  (get (:body response) :coordinateName) "FOO")))))
```

it fails with:

```
FAIL in (test-parser-rest) (parser_test_rest.clj:30)
put settings
expected: (= (get (:body response) :coordinateName) "FOO")
  actual: (not (= nil "FOO"))
```

Here's my handler:

```
(ns imp-rest.web
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:use ring.middleware.json-params)
  (:require [clj-json.core :as json])
  (:require [ring.util.response :as response])
  (:require [compojure.route :as route])
  (:require [imp-rest.settings :as s]))

(defn json-response [data & [status]]
   {:status (or status 200)
    :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}
    :body (json/generate-string data)}) 

(defroutes handler

   (GET "/settings" []
        (json-response (s/get-settings)))

   (GET "/settings/:id" [id]
        (json-response (s/get-setting id)))

   (PUT "/settings" [id value]
        (json-response (s/put-setting id value)))

   (route/not-found "Page not found") )

(def app
  (-> handler
    wrap-json-params))
```

which exposes this map (of settings):

```
(ns imp-rest.settings)

(def settings 
  (atom 
    {:coordinateName nil
     :burnin nil
     :nslices nil
     :mrsd nil
     }))

(defn get-settings []
  @settings) 

(defn get-setting [id]
  (@settings (keyword id))) 

(defn put-setting [id value]
  (swap! settings assoc (keyword id) value)
  value)
```

and the entry point:

```
(ns imp-rest.core
  (:use ring.adapter.jetty)
  (:require [imp-rest.web :as web]))

(defn -main
  "Entry point"
  [& args]
  (do        
    (run-jetty #'web/app {:port 8080})
    );END;do
  );END: main
```

Now when I 'lein run' I can make a (working) request like this:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"id" : "coordinateName", "value" : "FOO"}' \
    http://localhost:8080/settings
```

which is what I try to mock with the test. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How should the `PUT /settings work? Does it have `id` in the URL or as a part of the JSON request body?

Comment: Ideally id by URL, such that e.g. browsing to http://localhost:8080/settings/coordinateName gives "FOO".

Comment: I fixed your formatting which was non-idiomatic, esp. with respect to the placement of the parentheses. Probably you're using an editor which doesn't help you with seeing the structure of your code and get lost with the parens. Try to use one which helps you with that. Also try to stick to the usual formatting conventions (e.g. no blank before the closing parenthesis), so that people have it easier to see the structure -- you'll get used to seeing the structure without the parens yourself quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If you want to have `:id` in your `PUT /settings/:id` route accepting body in format `{"value": "..."}`, you need to change your routes definition:

```
(defroutes handler

  (GET "/settings" []
    (json-response (s/get-settings)))

  (GET "/settings/:id" [id]
    (json-response (s/get-setting id)))

  (PUT "/settings/:id" [id value]
    (json-response (s/put-setting id value)))

  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

And change how you call your `PUT` endpoint in the test:

```
(w/app 
  (-> (mock/request
        :put
        "/settings/coordinateName"
        (json/generate-string {:value "FOO"}))
      (mock/content-type "application/json")))
```

What was changed?

1. `:id` in your `PUT` URL route definition (`/settings` -> `/settings/:id`)
2. Your `PUT` request didn't send a correct request and content type.

#### If you want to have a `PUT /settings` route expecting `{"id": "...", "value": "..."}` request body, then you need to change how you create a mock request:

```
(w/app 
  (-> (mock/request
        :put
        "/settings"
        (json/generate-string {:id "coordinateName" :value "FOO"}))
      (mock/content-type "application/json"))
```

Comment: very, very helpful, thank you. There's a missing parentheses in the last code bit.

Comment: ring-mock provides `ring.mock.request/json-body` function so there's no need to manually encode body to JSON and set `Content-Type` header to `application/json`

Answer (score 2):

Your curl request specifies the parameters as JSON in the body of the PUT request, but your mock request tries to use URL parameters.

There are two options to resolve this:

- compojure can automatically translate parameters, but only when the relevant middleware is present -- you have `wrap-json-params` added to your handler, but you're missing [`wrap-params`](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.params.html#var-wrap-params). The answer from Piotrek Bzdyl amounts to making these params explicit in the compojure routes.
- Alternatively, you can add the ID/value pair as JSON in the body of the mock request using [`request.mock.body`](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring-mock/ring.mock.request.html#var-body).